# SKSpriteNode scaling quality

Tags: cocoa, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I'm working in a small OS X game using SpriteKit. There are some sprites, using textures created from an image, that can resize (from quite small 15-20 points to quite big 250-300 points).

I found when the sprite is small size, the antialiasing applied to it is not nice (borders are pixelated). SKTexture's filtering mode is set to Linear. I tried turning on mipmap usage, but it doesn't help (the image, then, is not pixelated but very blurry).

Any known solution? Is there a way to apply trilinear filtering to a SKTexture, just as in Core Animation layers?

Thanks!

Code within my SKScene subclass:

```
- (void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize
{
    for (Tile *tile in self.tiles)
    {
        tile.size = /* some complex calculations */;
        tile.position = /* some more complex calculations */;
    }

    for (Unit *unit in self.units)
    {
        Tile *tile = [self.tiles objectAtIndex:unit.locationIndex];
        unit.size = tile.size;
        unit.position = tile.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: how you scale the image?

Comment: I just change sprite's size by giving a new value to sprite's "size" property.

Comment: ok, you use this method because you have to give a precise dimension? if not you can try with .scale , and for me this do not ruin the images

Comment: Thanks, Ilario. Yes, I need an exact dimension...

Comment: can you post your code please? thanks

Comment: @Ilario Thanks. Code is very simple... just edited my post with the code.

Comment: I had the same problem, ended up making different textures for different sizes. The mipmap is really ugly + it doesn't work with texture atlas's. You can hotswap textures fairly quickly though, and even do it off the main thread without trouble.

Comment: Thanks @TheisEgeberg. Yes, I thought of that, it seamed to me that there should be a more elegant solution. It's kind of a shame that sprite scaling in Sprite-Kit is not better... I'll try, thanks!